# How to remove margin from the text area

Tags: html, css

I have a `textarea` and a `button`. I wanted them to be placed in a same horizontal line from the bottom.But when I place them inline with no style applied It is displayed like this:

[image: Image 1]

I am just unable to understand what is causing them to happen so?
Where is the extra margin coming from at the bottom of the text area?
And When I am doing the same thing with the form input they are okay as in the image 2:

[image: Image 2]

So what is causing `textarea` to behave like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        textarea,button
        {
            margin:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

<textarea>textarea</textarea>
<button>Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set the CSS for both of them to 0.  textarea,button {margin:0;} By default, the browser renders the elements with a default padding, margin and other values. You will have to manually initialize them to 0.

Comment: Add working code. It's so hard to debug your code from image.

Comment: This happens in Chrome, btw, not in Firefox, and it is not margin of elements...

Comment: Sorry for that I added code and @Highdef margin 0 thing is not working

Comment: It's what used to be called CSS reset. As @Highdef has said, set the margin to 0; you may also need to set padding to 0

Comment: So @sinisake how to fix that?

Comment: sorry @twoleggedhorse padding is not the problem there I tried it too still not working

Comment: @UtsavPrasad, vertical-align:bottom;

Comment: Thanks buddy@sinisake can you explain the behavior?

Comment: @UtsavPrasad, different browsers rendering of form elements, without user applied styling, i guess? So, yes, as others said - use css reset to remove all browser(s) defaults, and then apply your own styling...

Comment: @sinisake,thanks buddy i will keep that in mind!

Comment: The *cause* is the `-web-appearance:button` CSS attribute. It gives the element some additional properties that are built into the attribute and breaks the bottom alignment of the two elements. The *fix* is outlined in `barbarossa`'s answer.

Answer (score -2):

Add `vertical-align: bottom;` to your style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    textarea,button
    {
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
</style>
```

The issue is that setting them to `inline` elements messes with their vertical-alignment. The style will fix this issue.

Comment: The question isn't how to fix it, it's what's causing it: `So what is causing textarea to behave like this?`